Troubleshooting an RF driver for acousto-optic deflectors
I inherited an old acousto-optic deflector scanner but the catch is that one axis isn't working, and I want to troubleshoot why.
These acousto-optics deflectors are powered by an RF driver and that's pretty much all I know on the electronics side. My intuition was to check whether the controller actually outputs the RF driving signal. However, since I don't know anything about RF drivers (I'm more on the optics side...), I was scared that measuring this signal could damage my oscilloscope.
As this seems to be an old device, I could not find any information about it on the internet (axis model: R45100-5-6.5DEG-.51-Y, controller model: 21075-125-2ASVCO-2, from a company called Gooch & Housego). However, I found some generic information that might help:

"The piezo transducer excites a sound wave with a frequency of the order of 100 MHz and with an acoustic wavelength which is typically between 10 μm and 100 μm and an acoustic power e.g. of the order of 1 W to 10 W."

If I look at the Gooch & Housego website, recent deflectors have the following specs:

Center frequency (Fc) 87 MHz
RF bandwidth 55 MHz
RF power <1.5 W

I also found a manual for another RF driver for acousto-optic deflector from another company, which has the following specs:

Output RF Power >1.4 W
Output impedance 50 Ohms (nominal)

Based on this information, can someone help me devise a plan to troubleshoot this RF driver? Shall I put a 50 Ohms terminator and measure the voltage with an oscilloscope, assuming I am using a terminator that has a good enough power rating (perhaps 2W?) and that my oscilloscope has a good enough sampling? Can I be sure that I won't destroy my oscilloscope?
EDIT: I did measure the RF drive signal with the method outlined above. On the working axis, I could figure that the controller is a voltage-controlled oscillator (in retrospect I could have guessed from the model number, which has the letters VCO in it). When I measured the none-working axis, I figured that the button to toggle the output is not working properly. The whole button wiggles in its socket and when in certain positions, it can get the output right. The post was flagged as out-of-topic and I'm not entirely sure why, but I hope my edit will help clarify the situation.


Based on this information, can someone help me devise a plan to
troubleshoot this RF driver? Shall I put a 50 Ohms terminator and
measure the voltage with an oscilloscope, assuming I am using a
terminator that has a good enough power rating (perhaps 2W?) and that
my oscilloscope has a good enough sampling? Can I be sure that I won't
destroy my oscilloscope?

That seems a good plan. Connect the driver to oscilloscope with a 50 ohm coaxial cable, and add the 2W terminator at the oscilloscope-end of this cable.
Your oscilloscope should be able to accept at least 50v without overload. Many 'scopes go up to 50V scale.

50-ohm terminators for the BNC connection to oscilloscope may be a bit of a problem. There are a great many BNC 50-ohm terminators that can deal with low power of quarter watt to half-watt. Some higher-end oscilloscopes might also offer to switch-in a 50 ohm internal terminator - also low power. These all would be susceptible to overheating and destruction if you apply 2W power from your RF driver. A very brief measurement (a second or two) might limit overheating, depending on the thermal mass of the terminating resistor, but it is risky.

Thank you @glen_geek. Regarding the voltage of the RF output, do you know what it could look like? Because I cannot find information about it. We know it is in the order of one to ten watts, but current and voltages still elude me. Do you think I should use a Zener diode to protect the oscilloscope? Thanks again for your time and help. Much appreciated.

At those frequencies, output waveform is likely approaching sinusoidal shape. Would recommend not adding a clamping diode. See edit regarding terminator.

Thank you @glen_geek. Fortunately, I have a THORLABS T4119, which has the following description: "The T4119 is a 50 Ω feed-through terminator, which maximizes the signal bandwidth observable with our biased detectors. It can dissipate signals with input powers of 2 W (average at 25 °C) and frequencies up to 500 MHz." I think I'll take the risk and keep you updated. One more thing, in Fig. 3 of the manual of the driver from another company they have a plot of the RF output waveform and it is shown between -1 and 1. Can we assume those are volts?

A 2W feedthrough terminator sounds ideal. About Fig. 3 "waveform": a scale of volts from -1 to 1 would be rather low power into 50 ohms. Could be a normalized scale to show how much harmonic power is delivered, so you can perhaps estimate how much $2\theta, 3\theta...$ is generated versus $1\theta$

Perfect, thank you for your time and help. Have a great day!

I did measure the RF driver and updated my question to explain what was the issue. Thanks a lot for your help, it gave me the confidence to test the driver and I am grateful for your help.
